# Is thread a windows concept?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, operating-system

So i was reading "CLR via C#" and found this line "**A thread is a Windows concept whose job is to virtualize the CPU**". Really? Was single\multi thread originally from Windows?

Googling for justification did not help and hence seeking help from the community.

Comment: I think what the book means is that threads are managed by the Windows kernel and not the .NET runtime.

Comment: I think this question belongs on Programmers, but then, who am I. You can't even vote to move to Programmers any more.

Comment: That's an easy mistake to understand.  Technically, a thread is an Operating System-level concept. The O/S manages threads.  In the context of C#, in the majority of cases, (Mono not withstanding), the O/S will be Windows, so in this contect, usually it's a Windows-level concept.  Taken as a general, non-technical explanation of what a thread it, it makes sense.  It's not technically accurate, but your average newbie isn't going to know or care about the distinction.

Comment: "Telephone is an iPhone(TM) concept whose job it is to place telephone calls" :)

Comment: Certainly not.  Multiple execution units with separate stacks and shared memory have been around since the dinosaurs, (AKA IBM blue boxes, DEC red PDP11 and orange VAXes).  Certainly predates W3.1 which did not even have a scheduler worthy of the name.

Comment: This line appeared in the first chapter of 'Threading', where the author was exclusively talking about origins of thread in windows, when .NET was not born. I certainly don't want to get into an analysis\paralysis, but thank you for all the answers. @MrLister, I agree this should be in programmers; Not sure how to move it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, it's not solely a Windows concept, and the concept has been around for quite a long time.

Answer (score 10):

I suppose what the author really meant is that threading as a mechanism is something that is being managed by Windows and not .NET framework.

Comment: Which is blatantly wrong by the way, .NET threads don't map to OS threads, they can share a single thread and even switch to the more light weight fibers behind the scenes. They really are a .NET thing.

Comment: There's nothing in the C# documentation that says I cannot make blocking calls whenever I wish to.  They look and behave very like OS threads to me.  The Task manager seems to think so too: if I make 2000 threads with C#, the TM shows my process having 2001 threads.  It would be hugely unfriendly for .NET, (or any other framework or environment), to attempt to fiber/green my code.  I can't see how it could do it, TBH.

Comment: I agree, for now ,that CLR threads map to OS threads, but grapevine tells this may change in future(or may have already did in 4.5 or 5.0).

Answer (score 2):

I would say that that when we talk about "threading" on Windows there is a certain assumption about shared memory and implementation. I actually never heard the term "thread" until I moved to Windows programming (as opposed to embedded programming). I was more familiar with multiprocessing and multitasking. So the concept wasn't unique but the terminilogy may have changed. I would point out in my experience prior to Windows, multiple processes did NOT share memory unless it was global.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Amiga already had multithreading. Could it be that the text refers to that multithreading is (also) a Windows concept but not that it's (originally) a Windows invention?